# Error: Script file node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js does not exist

Tags: angular

C:\iDigital_10\Angular_f1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\helpers.js:177
throw new Error(`Script file ${input} does not exist.`);
^

Error: Script file node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js does not exist.
at C:\iDigital_10\Angular_f1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\helpers.js:177:23
at Array.reduce ()
at globalScriptsByBundleName (C:\iDigital_10\Angular_f1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\helpers.js:169:58)
at getCommonConfig (C:\iDigital_10\Angular_f1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\common.js:100:89)
[image]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

First of all refrain from using jquery in your angular project, if its unavoidable do the below steps.

method 1:

> npm i jquery --save

Then add jquery to `angular.json` using the below line.

> "scripts" :["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]

method 2:

Add the below script in index.html

```
<script
src=”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
integrity=”sha256–2z0P7MLoyxByUtvAk/xjkmindefS4auh4Pfzbm7y6g0=”
crossorigin=”anonymous”>
</script>
```

[adding jquery to angular](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-jquery-in-angular/)